# Qt Error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, qt, lnk2001

widget.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::mouseLeaveEvent(class QEvent *)" (?mouseLeaveEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQEvent@@@Z)

This is the error, which appeared in my project.
I have 2 header file and 2 source file, also main.cpp
In one of my header files i had a function like this:

protected:

virtual void mouseLeaveEvent(QEvent* event);

When this error appeared, i commented this function, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Most likely you don't define the `QWidget::mouseLeaveEvent` function, don't include in your build the source file that defines it, or don't include the library that defines it.

Comment: the reason is that this error appears in any project i open